# Today in history elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to capture the data in history today.
This Query returns empty. I want to ignore the years.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "02-15",
              "lte": "02-15",
              "format": "MM-dd"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/blog/an-introduction-to-elasticsearch-sql-with-practical-examples-part-1 I got help from article.

adapted it to myself [here](https://demo.elastic.co/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?load_from=https:%2F%2Fs3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2Fdemo.elastic.co%2Fquery_11a.json&_g=())

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "script" : {
            "script" : {
              "source" : "InternalSqlScriptUtils.nullSafeFilter(InternalSqlScriptUtils.eq(InternalSqlScriptUtils.dateTimeChrono(InternalSqlScriptUtils.docValue(doc,params.v0), params.v1, params.v2),params.v3))",
              "lang" : "painless",
              "params" : {
                "v0" : "created_at",
                "v1" : "Z",
                "v2" : "DAY_OF_MONTH",
                "v3" : 15
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script" : {
            "script" : {
              "source" : "InternalSqlScriptUtils.nullSafeFilter(InternalSqlScriptUtils.eq(InternalSqlScriptUtils.dateTimeChrono(InternalSqlScriptUtils.docValue(doc,params.v0), params.v1, params.v2),params.v3))",
              "lang" : "painless",
              "params" : {
                "v0" : "created_at",
                "v1" : "Z",
                "v2" : "MONTH_OF_YEAR",
                "v3" : 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this is how I solved the problem. maybe it will work for someone else.

Comment: well if you pass the 15 and the 2 in param you can just use a simple script :{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['created_at'].date.dayOfMonth == 66"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: I will try this. Thank you